# So slow when query

Tags: php, laravel

It took 20 seconds when I query

```
SELECT * FROM `form_edit` WHERE`unique_id_farmer` = 20220620175937762
```

It has `9` columns and the rows are `14895`.

Comment: 14895 isn't much. Are you sure this is the bottleneck? Nevertheless, you can index the column `unique_id_farmer` for better performance.

Comment: Thank you so much now it took 2. seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't that much matter how many columns there are that have the data you specified. What actually matters is the total number of data in table. To optimize your queries, you can use `index`-ing. To learn more about database indexing in `Laravel` see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#indexes).

You can index column in migration like:

```
$table->index('unique_id_farmer'); // will add index for your column
```

or

```
$table->unique('unique_id_farmer'); // will make column unique and add an index for it
```

Comment: Please look for duplicate questions on Stack Overflow before answering.  If a page can be resolved by pointing the asker to another Stack Overflow page, please flag/vote to close instead of answering.  I am not a Laravel user, but I could find multiple pages to close with.  If you can find better pages, I will be happy to add them to the dupe list.